# Is there a way to tokenize sentences and iterate 'div' and 'withTags' to a text?

Tags: r, tm, tidytext

I want to iterate 'div' and 'withTags' to a text file after tokenizing the file . I have been able to iterate with div and withTags to untokenized text . However I am getting error when I iterate div & withTags after tokenizing it . Is there any way out of it

text<- "It's unclear what Florida victory McEnany and Trump were referring to, but last month, the Supreme Court rejected an emergency petition for Democrat-led attempts in Florida to overturn a law preventing former felons from voting if they haven't paid all their fines or restitution. That is not necessarily related to mail-in balloting.
Meanwhile, the President's team is fighting to preserve aspects of mail-in voting they hope will offer Trump a strategic advantage."

```
library(htmltools)
library(tokenizers)
library(quanteda)

b <- tokenize_sentences(text)

trial <- b

buslist <- lapply(
  seq_along(trial),
  function(x, k){
    bus <- withTags(div(id = k,x[k]))
    return(bus)},
  x = trial)

names(buslist) <- q
```

getting this error :

```
`Error in writeImpl(text) : 
  Text to be written must be a length-one character vector
> `
```

Comment: I don't think your data `b` is in the format you were expecting. You have nested lists but seem to only be expecting a list. Try with `trial <- b[[1]]`

Comment: It works for first line or second line individually . I actually have a long text file of almost 1800 lines . How do get it for all the lines at once if you have some idea ?

Comment: @MrFlick : I also tried your hitherto solution which you gave on friday and used after tokenizing .It was giving me error so I used this iteration.

Comment: I'm not sure what your desired output is in that case. What ids should each value be assigned? If they all should be unique, maybe `trial <- unlist(b)` instead

Comment: wonderful ! it works with unlist()   :)